# MAMP - Apache couldn't be started

Tags: apache, mamp

I am running Yosemite 10.10.1 however had the same problem on Lion prior to upgrading (thought it would fix it!). Apologies if this has already been answered but I have searched hi and low and cannot find anything...

I have tried updating to the latest version of MAMP and renamed the envvars file, both have not fixed the problem.

When I start MAMP (not MAMP pro), it opens, when I click to start the servers I get "Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration".

Please someone help this has been driving me crazy, any help would certainly be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked Console to see if any errors are printed?

Comment: Did you check that you don't have something else listening on port 80?

Answer (score 3):

Had the similar problem-
Do the following

- Rename the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”
- In the file "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf" remove the line 
  LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so(86th line)(Use sublime Text/vim).
- Use default port numbers 8888 for Apache and 8889 for Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem I have. Going back to an older 3.0.x solves the problem. Just replace the htdocs and db folder with the ones before the update an it will run again.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when upgrading from 6.6 to 6.7. Seems that sometimes the Apache and MySQL servers keep on running during the upgrade and there is a problem binding to the port. What worked for me was this:

1. Completely quit MAMP.
2. Kill all Apache and MySQL processes using the `pkill` command:

```bash
pkill -f httpd && pkill -f mysql
```

3. Run MAMP again and set ports to 80/3306

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem for MAMP.
Suggest switching to XAMPP which perform exactly the same thing. it runs smoothly and with a better interface.

Comment: Please do not assume about "all solutions here". Because your observation might be not applicable to other users environment and there might be more answers in the future.